# Let k be an integer such that k divides n. Show that H = <r^k> is a normal subgroup of Dn (Dihedral group). Then, show that Dn/H is isomorphic to Dk.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let k be an integer such that k divides n. Show that H =  is a normal subgroup of Dn (Dihedral group). Then, show that Dn/H is isomorphic to Dk.

I am totally lost here. I know in Dihedral group, r^n=e=s^2, srs=r^-1. However, I don't know how to proceed this question.

Comment: Totally lost? Then first thing to do is to remind yourself of the definition of normal subgroup, and of $D_n/H$ (and second thing to do is to learn how to format mathematics on this website – check the Help menu).